# Permutations for 6 character password. From lower case letters or digits containing AT LEAST 2 lowercase letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We are required to come up with a $6-$character password. The password can contain any lowercase character and digits $(0-9)$ with repetitions allowed. Every valid password needs to contain at least $2$ lowercase characters. How many valid passwords are there?.

**Here's what I've got so far**

1. Total passwords ($x$) = $36^6$
2. Passwords with no letters ($y$) = $10^6$
3. Passwords with one letter ($z$)= $26^1$
4. Valid passwords = $x - (y + z) = 2.2 \times 10^9$

I would just like to know if my approach and the final answer is correct.
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: The amount of passwords with one letter is not $26^1$. It is $\binom{6}{1}26^1 10^5$

Comment: Approach is fine. $z$ is wrong. Compare $z$ and $y$ to see one problem. There is another coming from the fact that the single letter can (probably) be any of the six.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. So the final answer  would end up being $36^6 - (10^5 \times 26^1 \times 6^1 \times 10^6)$. Did I get that right?

Comment: Not quite.  You should *add* the number of ways of obtaining a password with no letters to the number of ways of obtaining a password with exactly one letter, then subtract the result from the total number of possible passwords.